# mod_rewrite for a 301 redirect. Not redirecting to proper location

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use a RewriteRule (using ISAPI, NOT on an Apache server) to 301 redirect a url such as:

> http://www.mydomain.com/news/story-title/

to

> http://www.mydomain.com/news/detail/story-title/

What I've gotten so far is:

> RewriteRule ^news/(?!detail)/?$ news/detail/$1/ [L,R=301]

which successfully ignores urls that already have the "detail" in them (in some of my first attempts I ended up with a loop and a url like "/news/detail/detail/detail..."), but visiting /news/story-title/ gives me a 404 so it's not redirecting to the proper location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rewrite rule to

```
RewriteRule ^news/(?!detail)([^/]+)/?$ news/detail/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

***EDIT** : (How it works?)*

`/(?!detail)` is a *negative lookahead* but it's also non-capturing i.e. it matches `/` but not what comes after it; just makes sure that it isn't "detail". So, I added a capturing group `([^/]+)` to capure those characters (one or more `+` of anything that's not a`/`) optionally ending with a `/`.

Hence, the `$1` now gets replaced with the matched directory name.

Comment: Your solution works great. Thank you.  Would you mind breaking down what each segment in your pattern does to help me understand it better?